# How to show brand & logo for every images on an E-Commerce website?

Tags: e-commerce, copywriting, branding, product-design, logos

I am working for an E-Commerce website, the company sells goods Online and they took photos from goods and products. They work on it a lot and spend time and money and don't like other websites copy their photo easily!

One of the team member here suggested putting the logo at center of every image, but I am against this!

I think this is a cheap work, we should be open-handed ;)
And I think there is no need to put a large logo on each image (product), or bold our logo, because user just need to see product not our logo, But they are afraid of people who may like to copy images and use it in their website.

My suggestion is we can just put a little nice logo at the top left of each image.

I like to know your suggestion, if you have any better idea.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the products sold in the e-commerce belong only to a company, you don't need to put the logo on it. Unless you don't want to cover the image with a logo, and for ecommerce, this is very bad because images are very important for users, I suggest to don't let others download your images. Just prevent the download of images, disabling the right click. Of course, if someone want to download it, it is possible through image urls in the html code. If you put a logo in the image, and the logo doesn't cover the product, it's useless, because if someone downloads it, he can just remove the logo and have the product's photo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, We can't prevent downloading because professional people always will find a way to download it. I think we should be more bounteous  and don't care what other websites want to do with our images!